# Creating multiple postgreSQL DB in existing RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have already created one postgreSQL database while creating RDS DB instance using cloudformation.

Now, I need to create another postgreSQL database in the same RDS DB instance.

How can I create, either using cloudformation or using console?

Is this possible? If so, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to it using any regular `postgreSQL` client, e.g. `psql` or `phpPgAdmin` and use SQL `CREATE DATABASE` query, as you would do on your local workstation.

Comment: Have used SQL workbench to connect to existing DB in RDS DB instance and executed 'create database db_name'. Database created successfully. Thanks!